# Ошибка: mysqli_fetch_array() expects parameter 1 to be mysqli_result, boolean given in

Tags: php, sql, mysqli

выдает ошибку в error_log : mysqli_fetch_array() expects parameter 1 to be mysqli_result, boolean given in

Сама часть кода:

```
<?php
  $rows = "";
    $podcat_id = $child->category_id;
    $lin = mysqli_query($link, "SELECT * FROM nqh02_jshopping_products_to_categories WHERE category_id = ".$podcat_id." ");
    while($row = $lin->fetch_array())
    {
      $rows[] = $row;
    }
    if ($rows[8]) {
      $int = array_splice($rows, -9);
    }
    else{
      $int = $rows;
    }
  ?>

  <?php for($i=0; $i < 8; $i++) {
    $id_p = $int[$i][product_id];
    $product = mysqli_fetch_array(mysqli_query($link, "SELECT * FROM nqh02_jshopping_products WHERE product_id =".$id_p." "));

  ?>
```

Ругается на строку с запросом. Подскажите, пожалуйста, решение этого вопроса

Comment: *Подскажите, пожалуйста, решение этого вопроса* Воспользоваться [поиском](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bmysql%5D+expects+parameter+1+boolean+given) и выбрать подходящее решение.

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php for($i=0; $i < 8; $i++) {
    $id_p = $int[$i][product_id];
    $product = mysqli_fetch_array(mysqli_query($link, "SELECT * FROM nqh02_jshopping_products WHERE product_id =".$id_p." "));

  ?>
```

Тут косяк. Попробуйте так:

```
<?php for($i=0; $i < 8; $i++) {
    $id_p = $int[$i][product_id];
    $query = mysqli_query($link, "SELECT * FROM nqh02_jshopping_products WHERE product_id =".$id_p." ");
    $product = mysqli_fetch_array($query);
?>
```

Comment: Попробовали, теперь эта же ошибка переводит на эту строку 
$product = mysqli_fetch_array($query);

Comment: А что возвращает $query? Может ошибка там?

Comment: Никакие данные не возвращает

Comment: Пробовали $row = $query->fetch_array() ?

Comment: еще нет, после чего мне ее вставить?

Comment: `<?php for($i=0; $i < 8; $i++) {
    $id_p = $int[$i][product_id];
    $query = mysqli_query($link, "SELECT * FROM nqh02_jshopping_products WHERE product_id =".$id_p." ");
    $rows = $query->fetch_array();
?>`

Comment: Страница полетела, а ошибка выводит PHP Fatal error:  Call to a member function fetch_array() on boolean in

Comment: Я в вашем листинге не вижу чтобы где-то собственно устанавливалась связь с БД. Переменной $link нигде ничего не присваивается, поэтому mysqli_query() выдаёт ошибку.

Comment: <?php 

$host = 'localhost'; 
$database = 'db'; 
$user = 'user'; 
$password = 'password'; 
$link = mysqli_connect($host, $user, $password, $database) or die("Could not select DB: ");


?> эта часть есть, просто сам код большой. Вообще-то сам код полностью был рабочим на другом сайте. При переносе шаблона на новый сайт он начал тупить и выдавать эти ошибки

Comment: @7koopa Ну сервер тебе упорно пишет про `boolean`! А такой тип значения возвращается только в случае ошибки. Ты же, вместо того, чтобы искать, почему ошибка, и смотреть сообщение об ошибке, полученное от MySQL сервера, упорно барахтаешься в коде, который сбоит как следствие этой ошибки...

Comment: Проверь, есть ли тут что либо: $id_p = $int[$i][product_id];
Возможно передаёт пустое значение в запрос, а запрос не отрабатывает. Либо сам запрос кривой. Надо дебажить. Тут чисто вопрос написания кода. Проверь каждую строку, возвращает ли она что нибудь.
И ещё, делай не $id_p = $int[$i][product_id]; а $id_p = $int[$i]["product_id"]; , из за отсутствия кавычек возникают ошибки. Не редкость